# add de Clase Derivada

Tags: java, poo

Quiero hacer un add de **Jugador que es derivado de Persona** en mi clase tengo un LinkedList,`List<Persona> personas`. ¿Hay algún medio de hacer este add? Lo que dice el enunciado es "Añadir una nueva persona de tipo jugador a la lista de personas."

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que he entendido quieres añadir un arrayList dentro de otro array:
Lo que he hecho es crear la clase persona que tendrá una lista de personas en este caso un jugador:

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    List<Jugador> jugador;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    public List<Jugador> getJugador() {
        return jugador;
    }
    public void setJugador(List<Jugador> jugador) {
        this.jugador = jugador;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona [nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + ", jugador=" + jugador + "]";
    }   
}
```

Clase Jugador:

```
public class Jugador extends Persona {

    private String apellido;

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hijo [apellido=" + apellido + "]";
    }   
}
```

El método main:

```
Persona persona;
        Jugador jugador;
        Jugador jugador2;
        List<Jugador> arrayH = null;//Declaras un array que recibe como parametro un objeto de la clase hijo
        String nombre1 = "jugador1";
        String nombre2 = "jugador2";
        String apellidoJugador1 = "Apellido jugador2";
        String apellidoJugador2 = "Apellido jugador2";
        int edad1 = 10;
        int edad2 = 12;

        jugador = new Jugador();
        jugador2 = new Jugador();
        jugador.setNombre(nombre1);
        jugador.setApellido(apellidoJugador1);
        jugador.setEdad(edad1);
        jugador2.setNombre(nombre2);
        jugador2.setApellido(apellidoJugador2);
        jugador2.setEdad(edad2);
        arrayH = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        arrayH.add(jugador);//Añades al array el hijo
        arrayH.add(jugador2);//Añades al array el hijo

        persona = new Persona();
        persona.setNombre(nombre1);
        persona.setEdad(edad1);
        persona.setJugador(arrayH);//Añade los hijo a la persona.

        System.out.println("Nombre: "+persona.getNombre());
        System.out.println("Edad: "+persona.getEdad());
        for (Jugador hijos : persona.getJugador()) {//Iterando el array de los hijos de la persona
            System.out.println(hijos.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Hola. Pero Persona no tiene ninguna lista, entonces quería saber si había medio de crear un Jugador o más, que son clases derivadas.

Comment: @LuísFilipe en la clase persona el atributo jugador es una lista, está declarado como List<Jugador> jugfador; Y en el main hago dos add, uno para jugador y otro para añadir ese jugador a la clase persona. Tú puedes crear tantos jugadores como quieras y añadirlos. Te he modificado el main, ahí he añadido dos jugadores a la lista.